# How to add primary key to component table with Nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a Nhibernate application configured using Fluent Nhibernate.

The database schema is generated automatically using SchemaUpdate upon application start.

The model has components, this components get created on the database as tables without Primary Key.

The database needs to be replicated using MS SQL Server Transactional Replication which requires Primary Keys on all tables.

Is there a way to have the Schema Update Tool apply a primary key to these tables?

Regards

Comment: Are you talking about ComponentMaps in Fluent NHibernate?  Maybe you can give an example mapping that you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Components in nhibernate are usually fully contained objects of the referencing object

The following is from the [Fluent-Nhibernate Mapping Documentation - ComponentMap<T>](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping)

```
public class Address
{
  public int Number { get; set; }
  public string Street { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string PostCode { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public PersonMap()
{
  Id( x => x.Id );
  Component(x => x.Address, m =>
  {
    m.Map(x => x.Number);
    m.Map(x => x.Street);
    m.Map(x => x.City);
    m.Map(x => x.PostCode);
  });
}
```

The Database should be

Table: Person

- Id
- Number
- Street
- City
- PostCode

Links:

- [nhibernate mapping component](http://ayende.com/blog/3937/nhibernate-mapping-component)
- [Fluent Mapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping)